# How to efficiently amend an std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, forwarding

Consider this situation:

```
void doSmth1(std::map<int,int> const& m);

void doSmth2(std::map<int,int> const& m) {
  std::map<int,int> m2 = m;
  m2[42] = 47;
  doSmth1(m2);
}
```

The idea is that `doSmth2` will call `doSmth1` and forward the map it received from its caller. However, it has to add one additional key-value pair (or override it if it is already there). I would like to avoid copying the whole thing just to pass an additional value to `doSmth1`.

Comment: Do not pass const reference and delete that `[42]` element after calling doSmth1().

Comment: @arrowdodger: And make sure you didn't overwrite an existing element with the same key.

Comment: You are passing the map by reference. You aren't copying anything other than then map's memory location.  I am not sure what you are concerned about.

Comment: @claireware: look at the assignment `m2 = m`. That copies everything in `m` to `m2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with the standard map. But if your problem is that specific, you might consider passing the new element separately:

```
void doSmth1(std::map<int, int> const & m, int newkey, int newvalue);

void doSmth2(std::map<int, int> const & m)
{
    doSmth1(m, 42, 47);
}
```

---

*Update:* If you really just want one map, and copying the map is out of the question, then here's how you can implement @arrowdodger's suggestion to make a temporary modification to the original map:

```
void doSmth2(std::map<int, int> & m)
{
    auto it = m.find(42);

    if (it == m.end())
    {
        m.insert(std::make_pair(42, 49));
        doSmth1(m);
        m.erase(42);
    }
    else
    {
        auto original = it->second;
        it->second = 49;
        doSmth1(m);
        it->second = original;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: This makes the most sense. _If_ `doSmth1` semantically expects just a map (which may be the case), then fall back to @arrowdodger's solution. And that's it.

Comment: You just moved the problem to doSmth1; m would most likely be a modified map for most implementations of doSmth1.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: well, whatever fits best. If the map is huge and modification isn't desired, then it may be preferable to pass the single amendment separately. Otherwise, arrowdodger's idea might be an option, too.

Comment: It seems to be a highly hypothetical situation. The "actual problem"(tm) might help for a solution.

Comment: As @CaptainGiraffe says, this moves the problem down, because `doSmth1` iterates over the elements, making me either duplicate code or add additional helper functions.

Comment: The edit is a quite elegant implementation of @arrow's suggestion, in my humble opinion. +1.